# Facebook Graph API Explorer won't POST scores

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

According to Facebook documentation:

"Create or update a score for a user

You can post a score or a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to /USER_ID/scores with the app access_token as long as you have the publish_actions permission."

So I obtain the app access token from the access token tool.  I have also verified that the publish_actions permission is enabled.

When I use the API Explorer for /USER_ID/scores with app access token I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

OK.  So I provide the user access token instead and I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: It works as long as authentication is set to WEB instead of Mobile/Native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to POST the score using the application token.  Since you are using the application token, you can no longer use /me so you will need to post to /userid/scores.  If your application token isn't working, try one in this format temporarily: appID|appSecret

You need to first make sure the user has granted publish_actions (verify by calling /userid/permissions).  You also need to make sure you application is marked as a game.

I just did this all myself via the Facebook Graph Explorer and it worked:
[image]

Comment: That also does not work.  I get error #15 again.  When I use the app token provided by the [access tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) I get "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Comment: Trying the appID|appSecret is new. Permissions verified.  App is verified as a game.   ![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/84KKA.png).  Still does not work.

Comment: I have also tried reseting the appSecret.  Does not work.  Registering a new game and trying it all over from the start also does not work.

Comment: Doing so gives me the error that I need a user access token.  It should be a simple task. I don't know what the problem is.  I have my apps classified as mobile/native apps.  Yours is not, right?

Comment: I made a Facebook app instead and it works on that.  Alright.  Will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you have built your own Action-Type in the Open-Graph then you should select "no" at "Requires App Token to Publish" in the Action configuration page. It fixed my issue with "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."