# Using Facebook scores API in an Android App?

Tags: android, facebook, api

I am integrating the scores API for facebook in an Android game. I had the exact same problem as this question: [Facebook Graph API Explorer won't POST scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536912/facebook-graph-api-explorer-wont-post-scores). The fix was to set my app as Web instead of Native/Desktop. Is it because scores API should not be used by native games? Is it somehwat dangerous to set up Web for a Native app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed this too, however I wondered if it is 'by design' as to use the Facebook Scores API you need access to the app access token (in order to do things like submit scores) however this isn't considered a safe thing to use from a native application. Here is a quote:

"App Access Tokens should only be used when the posting functions are originated directly from your servers in order to keep them private to the app. For example, you should not publish using an App Access Token from within a native mobile app. Doing that could allow the user to obtain the App Access Token, which could then allow them to take actions on behalf of your app. Instead, you should have your native mobile app queue actions up with your server and then have your server publish the stories to Facebook using the App Access Token."

Here is the website in question: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/.

So, it sounds like the only way to really use the Scores API is to have the native application securely talk to a separate, secure, server (potentially on Heroku) then once that server has verified the passed data, it would then talk to Facebook and submit the score using the app access token (which it can safely use without the user getting hold of it).

On top of this, the Facebook Scores API only supports having one score per application (not per level, per mode, etc.) scores, so in order to have anything more advanced the extra server is required anyway, so a database can be stored that maps Facebook user IDs to the various scores one wishes to score.