# Type of score for Facebook score API

Tags: android, facebook

I'm currently trying to implement an Android game with Facebook score publishing. I have multiple game modes and I'm currently wondering how I can store my scores.

On the official Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/), they are talking about a field called `type`. I haven't found a way to store the score's type yet.

Example:

```
posting those scores : "mode_1" => 22; "mode_2" => 21; "mode_2" => 12, ...
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The field "type" is present on the docs, but it's described nowhere where i can set it.

Comment: You can read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10683174/1393920