# Posting scores with app access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to post a score from my server.

- I have my app set up as a game.
- I've got my app access token.
- I'm POSTing to https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/scores
- I have authorized and given publish_stream and publish_actions permissions to my app for the USER_ID (which is me).

However, an error is telling me that I need a user access token for that action, which I don't as Facebook states here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/

> Create or update a score for a user
>
> You can post a score or a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   /USER_ID/scores with the app access_token as long as you have the
>   publish_actions permission.

I've seen a similar question but it was unanswered: [Facebook Graph API Explorer won't POST scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536912/facebook-graph-api-explorer-wont-post-scores) (they've ended up creating a new app, which is not a real solution)

To verify that it's not me who is incorrectly using the API, I went to Graph API explorer and tried it also there with the same access token, no luck:

[image: trying in Graph API]

Funny, that if I follow what it says and try the same with my user access token, it then says: `This method must be called with an app access_token.`

Is there something that I'm missing or is there a bug with the Graph API?

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: I know this answer, but i think i answered it yesterday too, give me a few mins to find the dupe (if it exists...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have everything correct, but there's one relatively little-known case which will produce that error message.

Check the 'App Type' field in the Advanced Settings:
[image: screenshot of the app settings interface]

If this is set to 'Native/Desktop' instead of 'Web' in the Advanced settings, it's assumed that your app's binary/native distribution contains the app secret.
In this configuration, API calls made with the app access token are untrusted, effectively the token is completely ignored.

Change the app settings back to 'Web' and you should be able to post or delete [Scores](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/) and/or  [Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/) with the [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/)

If this is the issue, you can quickly verify if with a call to 
`https://graph.facebook.com/app?fields=migrations&access_token=[APP ACCESS TOKEN HERE]`

In 'Web' mode, the response contains the migration settings for the app, something like:

```
{
  "migrations": {
    "secure_stream_urls": false, 
    "expiring_offline_access_tokens": false, 
    "requires_login_secret": false, 
    //etc
}
```

In 'Native/Desktop' mode, the app access token is untrusted, so you can't access the app's private data, and the response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Is there any problem with changing this setting? My app is a native iOS app, would this create any problems?

Comment: Unless the app secret is embedded in the iOS binary itself, there's no problem.
If you're using the app access token / app secret to make calls, you **need** to do it server side - otherwise users of your app could extract the app secret and make calls on behalf of your app - including changing settings, adding themselves as admins, redirecting your users to another site, etc

Comment: i'm doing everything on the server side (except first logging into facebook and sending it to the server to get facebook id, display prof. picture in app etc) and I'm doing all the updates to the graph API server side. i don't think one would ever put the app secret inside a binary that is distributed to users, but if that's the only case, then setting it as 'Web' is ok. for me.

Comment: I think in some of the older APIs the app secret was needed client side for login, and that setting made it safe to do so because all users could do with the app secret was log themselves into the app, which could also be done many other ways